NextJS, contentlayer causes build errors
When I'm trying to implement contentlayer in my nextjs app, I'm facing build errors:
web:build: TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'ConnectionOptionsReader' of 'i(...)' as it is undefined.
It mainly happens when I'm adding the following (which is necessary) in next.config.js:
const { withContentlayer } = require("next-contentlayer");

const nextConfig = {
`````````All of my code````````````
}

module.exports = withContentlayer(nextConfig);

I'm unsure what to do, it's supposed to be working fine but something seems wrong, thanks ahead.

have you configured tsconfig.json or jsconfig.json ? have you added the .contentlayer directory into your .gitignore you probably missed a step or more, follow along with the official Contentlayer docs here

I have configured everything as it says in the docs, that's to weird I'm lost.
